# Risks in open POP3/IMAP ports?

Tags: imap, pop3

I found a domain with open POP3 (110) and IMAP (143) ports. I was able to use TELNET to connect to them successfully, but beyond this is there any common vulnerability/exploit I should test on them, or is this even a security problem to have them open like this?

I've tried using USER and PASS and some common default user/password combinations, and they're not using a generic/default username/password from what I can tell.

Also I get the word "Fenix" on both of those ports. Is this the company hosting their IMAP/POP3 servers? I couldn't find any companies named Fenix that host these.

Comment: So what is your exact question about security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generic POP3 or IMAP vulnerability. In fact, you'll find open ports for this on many servers in the internet since these protocols are used to retrieve e-mail - hopefully in combination with TLS, i.e. after upgrading the initially plain connection to TLS using the STLS/STARTTLS commands.

There are though bugs in POP3 and IMAP servers too and probably more likely with IMAP since this is a way more complex protocol compared to POP3. A quick search for IMAP or POP3 on [cvedetails.com](https://www.cvedetails.com/) will show numerous known vulnerabilities from the past.

> Also I get the word "Fenix" on both of those ports. Is this the company hosting their IMAP/POP3 servers?

I'm not sure what exactly you are referring to but my guess is that you've seen this string in the first line you've got when connecting to these ports. Both IMAP and POP3 (and SMTP and FTP...) send after the connection a greeting from the server to the client and this greeting often contains a hostname or server type or whatever the admins liked to have there. Looking for [fenix imap](https://www.shodan.io/search?query=fenix+imap) at shodan returns something like this:

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 ... AUTH=PLAIN] Fenix ready.
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT ID CHILDREN NAMESPACE IDLE UIDPLUS AUTH=PLAIN
A001 OK Pre-login capabilities listed, post-login capabilities have more.
* ID ("name" "Dovecot")
A002 OK ID completed.
```

So according to the ID this is a [Dovecot](https://www.dovecot.org/) server, one of the major IMAP/POP3 server implemtations out there (and open source). It has a setting to set the greeting, i.e. a simple

```
login_greeting = Fenix ready
```

In the dovecot.conf will result in the same kind of response you see. So somebody decided that this might be a useful greeting and from the shodan query it looks like GoDaddy is behind at least many of such systems.